# pandas dataframe, regrouping

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Sentences':['Sentence1', 'Sentence2', 'Sentence3', 'Sentences4', 'Sentences5', 'Sentences6','Sentences7', 'Sentences8'],\
            'Start_Time':[10,15,77,120,150,160,176,188],\
            'End_Time': [12,17,88,128,158,168,182,190],\
            'cps': [3,4,5,6,2,4,5,6]}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 print(df)
```

[image]

Basically: Sentences, their start and end time, and the character per second.

Now, I also have a list:

```
time_list = [9,80,161,200]
```

Based on that list, I would like to regroup the sentences. The list lists the start and end-times of each group, i.e.

- 9 to 90: Sentences 1-3 (3 because majority of its time in that group)
- 90 to 161: Sentences 4-5 (sentence 6 does not belong in this group since the majority of its time is not in the group)
- 161 to 200: Sentences 6 (majority in the group), and Sentences 7-8

This is what I have done so far:

```
text = df["Sentences"].tolist()

df_text = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start', 'End', 'Text'])

switch = 1
collect_sentence = ""

for i_start, time_start in enumerate(df["Start_Time"]):
     time_end = df["End_Time"][i_start]

     if i_start > 0:
         time_list_start = time_list[switch-1]
         time_list_end = time_list[switch]


         if time_start >= time_list_start and time_end <= time_list_end:
             collect_sentence= collect_sentence + text[i_start]

         if time_start >= time_list_start and time_end > time_list_end and time_start < time_list_end:

             duration_before = time_list_end - time_start
             duration_after = time_end - time_list_end 

             if duration_after < duration_before:
                 collect_sentence + text[i_start]
             else:
                 df_text = df_text.append({
                                  'Start': int(time_list_start), 'End': int(time_list_end), \
                                  'Text': collect_sentence}, ignore_index = True)

                 switch += 1
                 collect_sentence = text[i_start]

         if time_start > time_list_end:
             df_text = df_text.append({
                                  'Start': int(time_list_start), 'End': int(time_list_end), \
                                  'Text': collect_sentence}, ignore_index = True)

             switch += 1
             collect_sentence = text[i_start]
```

[image]

As you can see the result is not what it should be. I feel like this is a bit of a mess currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
mean_time=df[['Start_Time','End_Time']].mean(axis=1).rename('Interval Time')
labels = ["{0}-{1}".format(time_list[i], time_list[i+1]) for i in range(len(time_list)-1)]

new_df= ( df.groupby(pd.cut(mean_time,bins=time_list, labels=labels,include_lowest=True))
            .Sentences
            .agg(','.join)
            .reset_index())
print(new_df)

  Interval Time                         Sentences
0          9-90     Sentence1,Sentence2,Sentence3
1        90-161             Sentences4,Sentences5
2       161-200  Sentences6,Sentences7,Sentences8
```

---

Using `time_list = [9,80,161,200]`:

```
  Interval Time                         Sentences
0          9-80               Sentence1,Sentence2
1        80-161   Sentence3,Sentences4,Sentences5
2       161-200  Sentences6,Sentences7,Sentences8
```

If you prefer create a list:

```
new_df= ( df.groupby(pd.cut(mean_time,time_list,right=False, labels=labels,include_lowest=True))
            .Sentences
            .agg(list)
            .reset_index())
print(new_df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Interval Time                             Sentences
0          9-80                [Sentence1, Sentence2]
1        80-161   [Sentence3, Sentences4, Sentences5]
2       161-200  [Sentences6, Sentences7, Sentences8]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask: How did you handle the special case of Sentence6 ?

Comment: I slightly updated my question, noticeably changing the time_list, to also include another edge case. Would you mind to have a second look at it ? Thank you so much ?

Comment: I have updated the solution. Before I was simply using End Time. Now what I do is use the average of EndTime and Start Time

Comment: I will include the output for that list

Comment: Wow ! Thanks a lot ! This is great- Nice idea with the Average.

Comment: I have included the result for this new case, keep in mind that when using the average of the two columns Start_Time and End_Time the correct interval will always be selected.

Comment: I think we should also include `include_lowest = True` as a precaution. You are welcome. I am glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

```
time_list = [9,90,161,200]
li={}
li1 = []
counter = 0
for i,j in zip(time_list, time_list[1:]):
    li[counter]=range(i,j)
    li1.append([counter,i,j])
    counter+=1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(li1, columns=['Group','Start', 'End'])
df1
  Group Start End
0   0   9   90
1   1   90  161
2   2   161 200
```

Created dataframe from timelist and also a dictionary with mapping of value range to a group number

```
data = {'Sentences':['Sentence1', 'Sentence2', 'Sentence3', 'Sentences4', 'Sentences5', 'Sentences6','Sentences7', 'Sentences8'],\
            'Start_Time':[10,15,77,120,150,160,176,188],\
            'End_Time': [12,17,88,128,158,168,182,190],\
            'cps': [3,4,5,6,2,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def f(row):
    val = range(row['Start_Time'],row['End_Time'])
    len_list=[]
    for k,v in li.items():
        len_list.append(len([i for i in val if i in v]))
    if max(len_list)==0:
        return None
    return len_list.index(max(len_list)) # returns first max of the groups when same length

df['Group'] = df.apply(lambda i:f(i), axis=1)
df.merge(df1, on='Group').groupby(['Start', 'End'], as_index=False)['Sentences'].sum()
Start   End Sentences
0   9   90  Sentence1Sentence2Sentence3
1   90  161 Sentences4Sentences5
2   161 200 Sentences6Sentences7Sentences8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! I slightly updated my question, noticeably changing the time_list, to also include another edge case. Would you mind to have a second look at it ? Thank you so much ?